# Effect of the Marcus Theory on Photosynthesis

Tags: biochemistry, photosynthesis

As far as I know, the Marcus Theory explains the rates of electron transfers in reactions as a function of differences in free energy between the product/reactant's potential well.

Furthermore, there is the so called inverted region which is often said to be important to explain effects as the photosynthesis. Sadly, I do not see the connection here. The inverted region seems to reduce the transfer rate in the backwards reaction but not in the forwards reaction which creates a net reaction flux. But how can this be explained by the Marcus Theory? I tried to read several sources which claimed to talk about this online, but apparently missed the crucial point.

Comment: Please provide a reference link to the Marcus Theory. I have never heard of it myself, and suspect that very few on this site will have.

Comment: @David I am tlaking about this theory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcus_theory Do you think I should rather ask this question at the chemistry stackexchange?

Comment: Not sure. I'd wait a little to see if anyone answers.